# editing HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior class android

Tags: java, android, animation, android-coordinatorlayout

I want to edit HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior class so that it can be reversed 
to work as HideTopViewOnScrollBehavior

### this is the class code :

> /**  * The {@link Behavior} for a View within a {@link
>   CoordinatorLayout} to hide the view off the  * bottom of the screen
>   when scrolling down, and show it when scrolling up.  */

```java
public class HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior<V extends View> extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V> {

  protected static final int ENTER_ANIMATION_DURATION = 225;
  protected static final int EXIT_ANIMATION_DURATION = 175;

  private static final int STATE_SCROLLED_DOWN = 1;
  private static final int STATE_SCROLLED_UP = 2;

  private int height = 0;
  private int currentState = STATE_SCROLLED_UP;
  private int additionalHiddenOffsetY = 0;
  @Nullable private ViewPropertyAnimator currentAnimator;

  public HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior() {}

  public HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onLayoutChild(
      @NonNull CoordinatorLayout parent, @NonNull V child, int layoutDirection) {
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams paramsCompat =
        (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    height = child.getMeasuredHeight() + paramsCompat.bottomMargin;
    return super.onLayoutChild(parent, child, layoutDirection);
  }

  /**
   * Sets an additional offset for the y position used to hide the view.
   *
   * @param child the child view that is hidden by this behavior
   * @param offset the additional offset in pixels that should be added when the view slides away
   */
  public void setAdditionalHiddenOffsetY(@NonNull V child, @Dimension int offset) {
    additionalHiddenOffsetY = offset;

    if (currentState == STATE_SCROLLED_DOWN) {
      child.setTranslationY(height + additionalHiddenOffsetY);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onStartNestedScroll(
      @NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
      @NonNull V child,
      @NonNull View directTargetChild,
      @NonNull View target,
      int nestedScrollAxes,
      int type) {
    return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
  }

  @Override
  public void onNestedScroll(
      CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
      @NonNull V child,
      @NonNull View target,
      int dxConsumed,
      int dyConsumed,
      int dxUnconsumed,
      int dyUnconsumed,
      int type,
      @NonNull int[] consumed) {
    if (dyConsumed > 0) {
      slideDown(child);
    } else if (dyConsumed < 0) {
      slideUp(child);
    }
  }
```

> /**    * Perform an animation that will slide the child from it's
>   current position to be totally on the    * screen.    */

```java
  public void slideUp(@NonNull V child) {
    if (currentState == STATE_SCROLLED_UP) {
      return;
    }

    if (currentAnimator != null) {
      currentAnimator.cancel();
      child.clearAnimation();
    }
    currentState = STATE_SCROLLED_UP;
    animateChildTo(
        child, 0, ENTER_ANIMATION_DURATION, AnimationUtils.LINEAR_OUT_SLOW_IN_INTERPOLATOR);
  }
```

> /**    * Perform an animation that will slide the child from it's
>   current position to be totally off the    * screen.    */

```java
  public void slideDown(@NonNull V child) {
    if (currentState == STATE_SCROLLED_DOWN) {
      return;
    }

    if (currentAnimator != null) {
      currentAnimator.cancel();
      child.clearAnimation();
    }
    currentState = STATE_SCROLLED_DOWN;
    animateChildTo(
        child,
        height + additionalHiddenOffsetY,
        EXIT_ANIMATION_DURATION,
        AnimationUtils.FAST_OUT_LINEAR_IN_INTERPOLATOR);
  }
```

```java
  private void animateChildTo(
      @NonNull V child, int targetY, long duration, TimeInterpolator interpolator) {
    currentAnimator =
        child
            .animate()
            .translationY(targetY)
            .setInterpolator(interpolator)
            .setDuration(duration)
            .setListener(
                new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                  @Override
                  public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    currentAnimator = null;
                  }
                });
  }
}
```

Can any one give me a source to learn about themes and animations in android?